# Ошибка: string is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
var result = string.replace('Тест', 'Тест2');
```

Смысл кода в том, что Javascript ищет в коде страницы слово тест и меняет на тест2, но в консоли пишет

> `ReferenceError: string is not defined`

В чем проблема?

Comment: Ну научитесь вы уже азам JS. А то так ничего и не поймёте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, укажи ему конкретную строку, где искать/заменять. Если хочешь заменить ВСЕ вхождения искомой строки то тогда регулярку надо

Например вот так:

```
var supertext = "Это некий длинный длинный текст в котром мы будем заменять строки и ещё что-то";
var resulted1 = supertext.replace("длинный","короткий");
var resulted2 = supertext.replace(/длинный/g,"короткий");
```

А так весь документ можно перелопатить

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/выйти/g,"вылезти");
```